# How to stop ListView from loading again when I press back button?

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview, android-listview

I created an Android application with three three Activities, **MainActivity --> SongActivity --> DownloadActivity**. The MainActivity and SongActivity are ListViews which fetch the list of items from mysql database. When I navigate back from SongActivity to MainAcitivty by pressing the back button, the ListView fetches the data again which makes the app navigation slower. Is there a solution for this?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.telugump3;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
  Activity context;
   HttpPost httppost;
   StringBuffer buffer;
   HttpResponse response;
   HttpClient httpclient;
   ProgressDialog pd;
   CustomAdapter adapter;
   ListView listProduct;
   ArrayList<String> records;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   context=this;
   records=new ArrayList<String>();
   listProduct=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.product_list);
   adapter=new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.list_item,R.id.pro_name, records);
   listProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
   listProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id){

           String sText = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pro_name)).getText().toString();
           Intent songIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SongActivity.class);
           songIntent.putExtra("movie_name", sText );
           startActivity(songIntent);

       }

   });
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       //create a LayoutTransition object       
      return true;
   }
   public void onStart(){
   super.onStart(); 
   //execute background task
   BackTask bt=new BackTask();
   bt.execute();

   }

  //background process to make a request to server and list product information
   private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{  
   protected void onPreExecute(){
       super.onPreExecute();
       pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
       pd.setTitle("Retrieving data");
       pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
       pd.setCancelable(true);
       pd.setIndeterminate(true);
       pd.show();       

       }

       protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){ 

       InputStream is=null;
       String result="";
       try{

           records.clear();

       httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
          httppost= new HttpPost("http://necrecords.16mb.com/getproducts.php");
       response=httpclient.execute(httppost);         
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             is = entity.getContent();

       }catch(Exception e){

       if(pd!=null)
       pd.dismiss();  //close the dialog if error occurs 
       Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());

       }

       //convert response to string
       try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();         
            result=sb.toString();
       }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error converting result "+e.toString());

}

       //parse json data
       try{

       JSONArray jArray =new JSONArray(result);
       for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                  String record=json_data.getString("pname")+"__"+json_data.getInt("uprice");
                  records.add(record);


          }


       }
       catch(Exception e){
       Log.e("ERROR", "Error pasting data "+e.toString());

       }

        return null;
       }   


       protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

       if(pd!=null) pd.dismiss(); //close dialog
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify the ListView to get new records

       }

}
}
```

**SongActivity.java**

```
package com.example.telugump3;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SongActivity extends Activity{
  Activity context;
   HttpPost httppost;
   StringBuffer buffer;
   HttpResponse response;
   HttpClient httpclient;
   ProgressDialog pd;
   CustomAdapter adapter;
   ListView listProduct;
   ArrayList<String> records;
   String mname;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.song_activity);
   context=this;
   records=new ArrayList<String>();
   listProduct=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.product_list);
   adapter=new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.newlist_item,R.id.pro_name, records);
   listProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
   TextView songtitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.movietitle);
   Intent iin= getIntent();
   Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

   if(b!=null)
   {
       mname =(String) b.getString("movie_name");
       songtitle.setText(mname);

   }

   listProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){ 

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id){

           String sText = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pro_name)).getText().toString();
           Intent songIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DownloadActivity.class);
           songIntent.putExtra("song_name", sText );
           startActivity(songIntent);

       }

   });

   }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //create a LayoutTransition object       
      return true;
}
   public void onStart(){
   super.onStart(); 
   //execute background task
   BackTask bt=new BackTask();
   bt.execute();

   }

  //background process to make a request to server and list product information
   private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{  
   protected void onPreExecute(){
       super.onPreExecute();
       pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
       pd.setTitle("Retrieving data");
       pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
       pd.setCancelable(true);
       pd.setIndeterminate(true);
       pd.show();       

       }

       protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){ 

       InputStream is=null;
       String result="";
       try{

           records.clear();

           String query = URLEncoder.encode(mname, "utf-8");
       httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
          httppost= new HttpPost("http://necrecords.16mb.com/getsongslist.php?password="+query);
       response=httpclient.execute(httppost);         
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             is = entity.getContent();

       }catch(Exception e){

       if(pd!=null)
       pd.dismiss();  //close the dialog if error occurs 
       Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());

       }

       //convert response to string
       try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();         
            result=sb.toString();
       }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error converting result "+e.toString());

}

       //parse json data
       try{

       JSONArray jArray =new JSONArray(result);
       for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                  String record=json_data.getString("allsongs")+"__"+json_data.getString("test");
                  records.add(record);


          }


       }
       catch(Exception e){
       Log.e("ERROR", "Error pasting data "+e.toString());

       }

        return null;
       }   


       protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

       if(pd!=null) pd.dismiss(); //close dialog
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify the ListView to get new records

       }

}
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add your 
 //execute background task

```
   BackTask bt=new BackTask();
   bt.execute();
```

in `onCreate()` **instead** on `onStart()`;

For more understanding please have a look at

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

**EDIT**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   context=this;
   records=new ArrayList<String>();
   listProduct=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.product_list);


 BackTask bt=new BackTask();
       bt.execute();


   adapter=new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.list_item,R.id.pro_name, records);
   listProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
   listProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id){

           String sText = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pro_name)).getText().toString();
           Intent songIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SongActivity.class);
           songIntent.putExtra("movie_name", sText );
           startActivity(songIntent);

       }

   });
   }
```

Comment: do this in all activities , replace your mainactivity oncreate with edit one

Comment: please explain problem ,

Comment: I have followed your edit and now MainActivity works fine. When i click on an item in MainActivity the app stops unexpectedly.

Comment: ok . good , what is exception then , this may be of your refereing ids , please crosscheck them

Comment: @tpA sir It's not working for me :( can u please help me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286800/how-to-stop-gridview-from-loading-again-when-i-press-back-button

Answer (score 0):

One way to make your activities respond better when you're checking for data remotely would be to cache data using onSaveInstanceState() and saving the record list in a bundle from which you can read during the onCreate() of your activity.

As just in case if the system decides to zap your activity from the stack then it'll try to load the data again from remote host (which could take a while).

Also yes you should execute the AsyncTask in onCreate() instead of onStart() and be sure to remove duplicates from your records list when fetching the data from your server.