# How to stop GridView from loading again when I press back button?

Tags: android, gridview

I created an Android application with Two Fragment, **MainFragment** --> **WebviewFragment**. The MainFragment is GridView which fetch the Grid Item from **Json** link. When I navigate back from **WebviewFragment** to **MainFragment** by pressing the back button, the Gridview fetches the data again. Is there any solution for this?

MainFragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    // Log tag

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url

    private static final String url = "http://api....";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    private GridView gridView;
    private TextView scrollingtext;
    private AppController appController;





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        movieList  = new ArrayList<Movie>();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
        scrollingtext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_annouc);
        scrollingtext.setSelected(true);
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.Grid_view);
        final CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);



            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("LINK","http://www.kalerkantho.com/");

                    Fragment newFragment = new WebviewFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    newFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                    transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();


                }
            });


        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage(" Loading ...");
        pDialog.show();

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                hidePDialog();

                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Movie movie = new Movie();
                        movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                        movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));


                        // adding movie to movies array
                        movieList.add(movie);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });



        // Adding request to request queue
        appController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
```

WebviewFragment

```
public class WebviewFragment extends Fragment {


    WebView webView;
    String newslink;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview,container,false);

        newslink = getArguments().getString("LINK");

        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl(newslink);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        return view;
    }
}


     }
```

Comment: Why you are finding id of view  in onCreateView()

Comment: Save your data in database or populate when get back from other fragment.

Comment: check your activity in settings of phone ,

Comment: I solved it from adding data again and again but why it's loading again when i'm pressing back? Why it's refresing. I want to stop refressing @tpA

Comment: I think this is because your activity/fragment is killed every time and again instantiated again

Comment: @tpA Sir, What should i do now? any solution for me?

Comment: @tpA Sir, I think you can help me !

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences to keep a flag of whether or not you already loaded the data and then check this flag whenever you switch between fragments.

You should also keep the data in either SharedPreferences as well if your flag is active or maintain an internal database and load that instead of transforming your JSON again.

Answer (score 1):

You can done this by using Fragment. Making your main content parent layout as Framelayout and inflate the Webview when pressing a button or what you want by using the command fragment.add and when backpress just use fragment.remove.

Answer (score 1):

inflated `view` wouldn't be `null` when you `popback`. so just inflate view when you replace `Fragment`

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    if (view ==null){//null means fragment replaced  and not null means popbacked 
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
     init();
   }

    return view;
}

private void init() {
    scrollingtext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_annouc);
    scrollingtext.setSelected(true);
    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.Grid_view);
    final CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("LINK", "http://www.kalerkantho.com/");

            Fragment newFragment = new WebviewFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            newFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();


        }
    });
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage(" Loading ...");
    pDialog.show();

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            hidePDialog();

            // Parsing json
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {

                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Movie movie = new Movie();
                    movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                    movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));


                    // adding movie to movies array
                    movieList.add(movie);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // notifying list adapter about data changes
            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });
    // Adding request to request queue
    appController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `setRetainInstance(true);` in `MainFragment` which will keep the instance state.

Hope this helps.